# conditions for ($x$,$y$,$z$) so that it is a linear combination of 3 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: q3]

I have tried solving this question for co-efficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that these can be coefficients for each of the vectors in the question so that the equation is satisfied. However, all I get is the trivial solution. Any ideas how I should solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

- The rank of $\{(-8,3,4),(-2,1,0),(-13,5,6)\}$ is $2.$ So the linear span is a plane.
- A vector which is a linear combination of the above three vectors must lie in the plane.

Comment: so should i find the equation of the plane using those 3 vectors?

Comment: It is a way to solve the question. If you find the equation of the plane then you have the equation satisfied by $(x,y,z).$

Comment: thank you for your assistance! I successfully solved the question